# Python Perfect Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am supposed to write a Python program that will identify and print all the perfect numbers in some closed interval [ 2, n ], one per line. We only have to use nested while loops/ if-else statements. I did it somehow using a for loop, but can't figure out the same using a while loop. I'd appreciate your help if you could show me how to translate my code into a while loop. Thanks guys. Here's what I have:

```
limit = int(input("enter upper limit for perfect number search: "))

for n in range(2, limit + 1):
    sum = 0
    for divisor in range(1, n):
        if not n % divisor:
            sum += divisor
        if sum == n:
            print(n, "is a perfect number")
```

Comment: Many people here are able to give you the solution, but it would be far better if you could come up with it yourself, to become a better programmer. Ask yourself "when should the while-loop be terminated" and incorporate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
limit = int(input("enter upper limit for perfect number search: "))

n = 1

while n <= limit:

    sum = 0
    divisor = 1
    while divisor < n:
        if not n % divisor:
            sum += divisor
        divisor = divisor + 1
    if sum == n:
        print(n, "is a perfect number")
    n = n + 1
```

Comment: Thanks to both responses first of all. See the thing is I cannot use for loops at all. So, that was my issue. How would you resolve the inner for loop then?

Comment: I revised my answer check it to see the solution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a (somewhat more efficient) sieve version:

```
# search all numbers in [2..limit] for perfect numbers
# (ones whose proper divisors sum to the number)
limit = int(input("enter upper limit for perfect number search: "))

# initialize - all entries are multiples of 1
#   (ignore sieve[0] and sieve[1])
sieve = [1] * (limit + 1)

n = 2
while n <= limit:
    # check n
    if sieve[n] == n:
        print(n, "is a perfect number")
    # add n to all k * n where k > 1
    kn = 2 * n
    while kn <= limit:
        sieve[kn] += n
        kn += n
    n += 1
```

---

Running it to 10000 finds

```
6 is a perfect number
28 is a perfect number
496 is a perfect number
8128 is a perfect number
```

and factorizing those shows an interesting pattern:

```
6          3 * 2                         (  4 - 1) * (  4 / 2)
28         7 * 2 * 2                     (  8 - 1) * (  8 / 2)
496       31 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2             ( 32 - 1) * ( 32 / 2)
8128     127 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2     (128 - 1) * (128 / 2)
```

where the first factor (3, 7, 31, 127) is a prime which is one less than a power of two, and it is multiplied by half that same power of two. Also, the powers involved are prime (`2**2`, `2**3`, `2**5`, `2**7`).

In fact Euclid proved that `(2**p - 1) * 2**(p - 1)` is a perfect number if `2**p - 1` is prime, which is only possible (though not assured) if `p` is prime. Euler went further, proving that all even perfect numbers must be of this form.

This suggests an *incredibly* more efficient version - I am going to go ahead and use for loops, feel free to rewrite it without. First, we need a source of primes and an is_prime test:

```
def primes(known_primes=[7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]):
    """
    Generate every prime number in ascending order
    """
    # 2, 3, 5 wheel
    yield from (2, 3, 5)
    yield from known_primes
    # The first time the generator runs, known_primes
    #   contains all primes such that  5 < p < 2 * 3 * 5
    # After each wheel cycle the list of known primes
    #   will be added to.
    # We need to figure out where to continue from,
    #   which is the next multiple of 30 higher than
    #   the last known_prime:
    base = 30 * (known_primes[-1] // 30 + 1)
    new_primes = []
    while True:
        # offs is chosen so  30*i + offs cannot be a multiple of 2, 3, or 5
        for offs in (1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29):
            k = base + offs    # next prime candidate
            for p in known_primes:
                if not k % p:
                    # found a factor - not prime
                    break
                elif p*p > k:
                    # no smaller prime factors - found a new prime
                    new_primes.append(k)
                    break
        if new_primes:
            yield from new_primes
            known_primes.extend(new_primes)
            new_primes = []
        base += 30

def is_prime(n):
    for p in primes():
        if not n % p:
            # found a factor - not prime
            return False
        elif p * p > n:
            # no factors found - is prime
            return True
```

then the search looks like

```
# search all numbers in [2..limit] for perfect numbers
# (ones whose proper divisors sum to the number)
limit = int(input("enter upper limit for perfect number search: "))

for p in primes():
    pp = 2**p
    perfect = (pp - 1) * (pp // 2)
    if perfect > limit:
        break
    elif is_prime(pp - 1):
        print(perfect, "is a perfect number")
```

which finds

```
enter upper limit for perfect number search: 2500000000000000000
6 is a perfect number
28 is a perfect number
496 is a perfect number
8128 is a perfect number
33550336 is a perfect number
8589869056 is a perfect number
137438691328 is a perfect number
2305843008139952128 is a perfect number
```

in under a second  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can replace your `for` loops with the following:

```
n = 2
while n < limit + 1:
   ...
   divisor = 1
   while divisor < n:
      ...
      divisor += 1
   ...
   n += 1
```

Hint: You can also use `n/2` as the upper limit for the second loop as any divisor of `n` cannot be greater than `n/2`.

Comment: Just saw this. let me try and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing this codes for alternative. Perfect number is of the form  [2^{n-1}(2^{n}-1)] where 2^{n}-1 and n both are prime numbers.

```
for num in range(2,101):
if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
    num_2=num*2-1
    for num_2 in range(2,101):
        if all(num_2%i!=0 for i in range(2,num_2)):
            MükemmelSayı=2**(num-1)*(2**num-1)
            print(MükemmelSayı)
            break
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave you an alternative of the code:

```
def perfect(x:int, i:int = 2, z:int = 0) -> int or bool:
    while z != x:
        z = (2**(i-1))*((2**i)-1)
        i+=1
        if z > x:
            break
            return False
    return z

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = int(input("Digita un número:  "))
    print('Es un numero perfecto ' if n == perfect(n) else 'No es un numero perfecto')
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
T = int(input())
list1 = list()
for i in range(0,T):
    N = int(input())
    list1.append(N)
    list1 = [int(i) for i in list1]
sum = 0
for ele in list1:
    for j in range(1,ele):
        if ele % j == 0:
            sum = sum + j
    if sum==ele:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('false')
```