# I want to print all the perfect numbers between 1 to 20

Tags: python

```
n=1
Sum=0
while n<=20:
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if(n%i==0):
            Sum+=i
        if(Sum==n):
            print(Sum)
    n+=1
```

I need to print all the perfect numbers between 1 to 20.

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Comment: i couldn't print them with this code

Comment: Then write in the question, what does the code print and what do you expect it should do.

Comment: In that case you need to explain what the problem is and the desired output **in your question**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Perfect Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496253/python-perfect-numbers)

Comment: Can you add output example and expected output so we can try to solve issue

Comment: Why are you using `n` if your range makes `i` the same value?

Comment: [Perfect Number - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) says: that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors, *excluding the number itself*. The other issue is resetting sum to zero after each number is tested.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you never reset the sum but it should be reset for every new number you try. Otherwise `Sum` will grow over `n`.

Another issue is, that according to the definition of a perfect number, the number itself is excluded in the division test. But since you run up to `n+1`, the number itself will always be added and thus `Sum` is always greater than `n`.

Third issue is the indentation of the second `if`. It will print more often than you expect.

Fixing the code is left as an exercise for the reader. If you want a copy&paste solution, there are probably plenty enough on the Internet.

---

Besides these primary issues which prevent you from the correct results, the code could be improved in several aspects

- Python coding style: remove the redundant parentheses
- Clean code: naming of the variables
- Reuse: define a method `is_perfect(number)`
- Use type hints: `def is_perfect_number(number:int)->bool:`
- Performance: division check needs to run until n/2 only.

Comment: why until `sqrt(n)` and why in steps 2? maybe I misunderstood something but if you meant to do that with `n % i`, then it seems a bit wrong, so 6 is a perfect number `n = 6`, if `i` is checked in steps of 2, then it will skip 1 and 3 which are divisors of 6 and `sqrt(n)` will return a number that is less than half of the number while that the half is also a divisor (I mean it could be accounted for later I guess), correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Matiiss: thanks. That was for prime numbers. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect number is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

To achieve that, I would isolate the perfect number check in a function as follows:

```
def is_perfect(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,n//2+1):
        if(n%i==0):
            s += i
    return n == s    

n=20
print([x for x in range(1, n+1) if is_perfect(x)])
```

Comment: `int(n / 2)` can be written as `n // 2`, will make it a bit faster

Comment: @Matiiss well spotted! Thanks! Code changed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Separate the perfection check (sum of divisors == number) from the searching (range for numbers up to 20).

```
def isPerfect(n):
    return 2*n == sum(sum({d,n//d}) for d in range(1,int(n**0.5)+1) if n%d==0)

for n in range(1,21):
    if isPerfect(n): print(n)
```

*BTW, there is only one perfect number (6) from 1 to 20 so you may want to broaden that range.*